# Unity how can AddComponent<T>()?

Tags: c#, methods, unity-game-engine

I need to attach a specific script to a GameObject.

```
public T ElegirScript<T>()
    {
        switch((int)tipoEdificio)  // enum
        {
        case 0:

            return Edificios;  // a class/script not instance
            break;
        case 1:

            return PlantaEnergia;  // a class/script not instance
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }


gameobject.AddComponent<ElegirScript()>();
```

How can I make this? I have errors, thanks.

I need first a Method that returns a type or a component, the return must be scripts. then I AddComponent and give the type the program choose, How can I do this? Examples.

Comment: What are your errors? Include them in your question! :)

Comment: thats not how generics work https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant use a non component type class with Add component. Meaning that your class has to inherit from MonoBehaviour  to be able to be added to a gameObject. And secondly thats not how you use generics in the first place. IF you just want to add a different component bases on a condition why even bother with generics just try :

```
if(condition)
gameObject.AddComponent<MyMonoBehaviourClass1>();
else
gameObject.AddComponent<MyMonoBehaviourClass2>();
```

I finally managed to do what Op wanted but granted its not a generic solution.
Chages to OP code :

```
public Type ElegirScript()
    {
        switch ((int)tipoEdificio)  // enum
        {
            case 0:
                return typeof(Edificios);  // a class/script not instance
            case 1:
                return typeof(PlantaEnergia);  // a class/script not instance
            default:
                return null;//Or throw exception here
        }
    }
```

Now you can call `gameObject.AddComponent(ElegirScript());` and it works just fine.

Comment: Dont understand, I need a method that return a TYPE, or COMPONENT for do addComponent<TYPE>()

Comment: I think you are very confused. You cant call a method as the type for AddComponent. Even if your method returns a Type.

Comment: ok, then I must always specific the component to the program?? canno the program make the decision?

Comment: Yes, this works, but my question was for make it more quickly. A method when I call the addComponent, but if it isnt possible, this solve the problems, thanks.

Comment: @JoeBlow is it possible that we start a chat. I have been thinking about ways to pass the result of a method to AddComponent and cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: @user3481415 please check my edit and tell me if this is the desired behavior.

Comment: I did like the first mode.