# (Unity) How to use AddComponent with a Generic Type

Tags: c#, generics, unity-game-engine, components

I'm trying to add components from a List.

Here is a very similar situation, except he isn't grabbing them from a List.
[Unity how can AddComponent<T>()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37207045/unity-how-can-addcomponentt)

Here is my Code so far, but I really don't know where to go from this. It is C# by the way, I just don't see an option for it, so I am sorry for that.

It kind of works, it does add a component with no errors, but the component it adds is blank.

Edit: I forgot to add the AddComponentToObject. Here is full code now.

```
public class LittleComponent : MonoBehaviour {

    public List<UnityEngine.Object> specialScripts = new List<UnityEngine.Object>();

    public Type GenericSpecialtyScript(int script)
    {
        return specialScripts[script].GetType();
    }


    public void AddComponentToObject(GameObject addToObject)
    {

        GenericSpecialtyScript(0);
        addToObject.AddComponent<GenericSpecialtyScript>();

    }
}

public class GenericSpecialtyScript : MonoBehaviour
{

}
```

And here is how I am testing it. Its just an editor script.

```
public void TestButton()
{
    if (GUILayout.Button("Test", GUILayout.Height(30)))
    {
        _LittleComponent.AddComponentToObject(_LittleComponent.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is years old, but someone on the Unity forums had found a way and put it on github. https://github.com/Baste-RainGames/RuntimeScriptField_Unity

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add a bunch of components from a list to a GameObject then you could use a list of [Type](https://www.dotnetperls.com/type)'s.

```
public class MultiComponentAdder : MonoBehaviour {
  List<Type> types = new List<Type>();

  void Awake () {
    types.Add(typeof(Apple));
    types.Add(typeof(Orange));
    types.Add(typeof(Banana));

    foreach (var t in types)
    {
        this.gameObject.AddComponent(t);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What if I don't know the type before though?
I'm creating an editor Tool, and I don't want people to have to do any coding.